# insert only new data instead duplicate the existing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I have this code running calling the data from the core system,

```
  public int MuatTurunMTS(hopesWcfRef.Manifest2 entParam, string destination, int capacity)
        {
        try
        {
            EL.iSeriesWcf.IiSeriesClient iClient = new iSeriesWcf.IiSeriesClient();

            EL.iSeriesWcf.Manifest2 manifest2 = new iSeriesWcf.Manifest2();
            manifest2 = iClient.GetManifest2(entParam.NOKT, destination, capacity);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = manifest2.Manifest2Table;

            List<hopesWcfRef.Manifest2> LstManifest2 = new List<hopesWcfRef.Manifest2>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                hopesWcfRef.Manifest2 newDataRow = new hopesWcfRef.Manifest2();

                newDataRow.NOPASPOT = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                newDataRow.NOKT = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                newDataRow.KOD_PGKT = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                newDataRow.KOD_KLGA = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                newDataRow.NAMA = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
                newDataRow.TKHLAHIR = (dt.Rows[i][5].ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][5]));  //Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][5]);
                newDataRow.JANTINA = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString();
                newDataRow.WARGANEGARA = dt.Rows[i][7].ToString();
                newDataRow.JNS_JEMAAH = dt.Rows[i][8].ToString();
                newDataRow.NO_SIRI = dt.Rows[i][9].ToString();
                newDataRow.NO_MS = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][10]);
                newDataRow.BARKOD = dt.Rows[i][13].ToString();
                newDataRow.NO_DAFTAR = dt.Rows[i][14].ToString(); 

                //bydefault make cell empty
                newDataRow.STS_JEMAAH = "";
                newDataRow.SEAT_NO = "";
                newDataRow.SEAT_ZONE = "";
                newDataRow.BERAT = 0;
                newDataRow.JUM_BEG = 0;

                LstManifest2.Add(newDataRow);
            }

            int cntr = 0;
            if (LstManifest2.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (hopesWcfRef.Manifest2 manifest in LstManifest2)
                {
                    cntr++;
                    SaveManifestTS(manifest);
                }
            }

            return LstManifest2.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And goes to :

```
 public void SaveManifestTS(hopesWcfRef.Manifest2 manifest)
         {
             try
             {
                 ent.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch, null, null);
                 ent.AddObject("Manifest2", manifest);
                 ent.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
              }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 //Uri u = new Uri(ent.BaseUri + "GetErrorMsg"
                 //              , UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                 //string datas = (ent.Execute<string>(u)).FirstOrDefault();
                 //Exception ex = new Exception(datas);
                 throw ex;
             }
         }
```

When SaveChanges run, if the data exist it will duplicate the entire row,
How to avoid the data being duplicate when insert (savechanges)??????
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about: Do not insert.

In these cases I am using a MERGE statement that updates existing data (based on primary key) and inserts new data.

Oh, and all the code example you loved to post is totally irrelevant to the question, which is a pure SQL side question. You literally quote your car manual then asking which direction to turn.

Comment: I don't want the existing data to be updated if exist. Only will insert a new data only without update the existing data.

Comment: THen program it like this. Same command. Just - ah - writing some code.